# Rename multiple files remove all characters

Tags: rename, filename

How can I replace this

```
[www.Example.com]Name-episode-77.mp4
FGBs episode 3 dks.mp4
```

to

```
HxH 077.mp4
HxH 003.mp4
```

*Files name doesn't follow exact pattern

### I want to :-

- Remove all characters and symbols
- Format number from 3 to 003
- Add string at the beginning of filename

Comment: `$0` is the name of the program. `$1` is the first argument to the program. write a script that lists the files, or turns them into arguments, then rename them. HxH 077.mp4 doesn't mean anything to me, are all the files named HxH*3[0-9]*.mp4?   perhaps you should grep out the "episode-N" and assign that to a temp variable, before renaming the file. You might also output a log, so you can know what  was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner works for your example data:

```
for i in *; do echo "$i";mv "$i" $(echo "$i" | perl -ne '($num)=$_=~/(\d+).*\.mp4/; print "HxH",sprintf("%03d",$num),".mp4","\n"'); done;
```

Explanation:

```
for i in *; 
do 
  echo "$i";
  mv "$i" $(echo "$i" | perl -ne '($num)=$_=~/(\d+).*\.mp4/; print "HxH",sprintf("%03d",$num),".mp4","\n"'); 
done;
```

`for i in *;do` -> loop through all files in current directory
`echo "$i";` -> write current file (see progres/logging)
`mv "$i" $(echo "$i" | perl -ne '($num)=$_=~/(\d+).*\.mp4/; print "HxH",sprintf("%03d",$num),".mp4","\n"');` -> renaming command (original name to output of perl command) The perl command extract digits from given filename and print "HxH", the number with leading 0s and ".mp4"

---

Important Note:

The command given works on the two sample inputs you provided. You should definitely test it before applying it to your actual files. Therefore I would recommend removing `mv "$i"` from the command. Then you can validate the names.

Comment: can I add if conduction to this code ?

Comment: yes, of course. If you have questions to the code or you have filenames, that break it, you can leave me a comment

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use `rename` (the perl version, which is the standard one that come with Ubuntu) and a regular expression (RE):

```
rename -vn 's/.*?([0-9]+).*/sprintf("HxH %03d.mp4", $1)/e' *.mp4
```

Step by step:

1. `rename -vn` will say (`-v`) what renames it will perform but without doing them (`-n`);
2. For every name substitute (`s`) the first RE with the second string, separated by `/`;
3. The first RE matches zero or more chars in non-greedy way (`.*?`), followed by one or more digits (`[0-9]+`), followed by whatever; the digits match is saved in the first group thanks to the parenthesis (`(...)`);
4. The second string expands to the perl command `sprintf("HxH %03d", $1)` where `$1` is the first group matched above;
5. The flag `e` to the `s` command says that I want to *execute* the replacement expression and use the result, so the `sprintf` is execute and prints the number in `$1` in a field of size 3 with leading zeroes (`"%03d"`);
6. Finally, apply the `rename` command to all files ending in `.mp4` (`*.mp4`).

See:

```
% ls
FGBs episode 3 dks.mp4  [www.Example.com]Name-episode-77.mp4
% rename -vn 's/.*?([0-9]+).*/sprintf("HxH %03d.mp4", $1)/e' *.mp4
FGBs episode 3 dks.mp4 renamed as HxH 003.mp4
[www.Example.com]Name-episode-77.mp4 renamed as HxH 077.mp4
```

Note that this is just a test run; renames can't be undone... let's run that for real now:

```
% rename -v 's/.*?([0-9]+).*/sprintf("HxH %03d.mp4", $1)/e' *.mp4 
FGBs episode 3 dks.mp4 renamed as HxH 003.mp4
[www.Example.com]Name-episode-77.mp4 renamed as HxH 077.mp4
% ls
HxH 003.mp4  HxH 077.mp4
```

Regular expression are really powerful.

Notice that only the first set of numbers will be used:

```
% touch "Another serie 2 ep 34.mp4"
% rename -vn 's/.*?([0-9]+).*/sprintf("HxH %03d.mp4", $1)/e' *.mp4
Another serie 2 ep 34.mp4 renamed as HxH 002.mp4
```

To avoid that... study for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320525/regular-expression-to-match-last-number-in-a-string and be careful with the "4" in "mp4"...

Moreover, it will fail if the name contains *no* numbers --- see the @kos' comment below.

Comment: The only flaw would be a file with no numbers, which would be renamed to "HxH 004.mp4". Maybe `\..*` after the last `.*`?

Comment: @kos yes --- good idea. I'll add a notice.